# Emacs Anything and rgrep

Tags: emacs, grep

[Anything](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Anything) is freaking awesome! Especially when it comes to files and anything-do-grep. Only problem is anything-do-grep doesnt search recursively. Is there a way to tell it to do so?

Thanx!

Comment: For those who don't know it an introduction to Anything: http://metasandwich.com/2010/07/30/what-can-i-get-for-10-dolla-anything-el/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The last bit of the docstring of anything-do-grep says:

> If a prefix arg is given use the -r option of grep. The prefix arg can
>   be passed before or after start.

And, yes, Anything is freaking awesome.

EDIT: Just press <kbd>C-u</kbd> before executing "anything-do-grep". If you're selecting "anything-do-grep" from a menu, just press <kbd>C-u</kbd> before clicking on the menu item.

EDIT: In response to your question about setting a keybinding to call "anything-do-grep" with a prefix arg, here's some sample code that will do this:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c g")
                (lambda () (interactive)
                  (let ((current-prefix-arg '(4))) ; C-u
                    (call-interactively 'anything-do-grep))))
```

Comment: I've edited my answer with instructions for how to enter a prefix arg.

Comment: Thank you very much, is there a way to bind all this(the prefix and the anything-do-grep) to a chord?

Comment: I've edited my answer with some sample code for binding all this(the prefix and the anything-do-grep) to a chord.

Comment: ok i copied the whole `anything-do-grep-l`(and renamed it) in my .emacs and modified it so that it only asks for pattern :D

Comment: Copying this here since it took me forever to figure out. This greps  in my projects dir only in .clj and .cljs files: (defun project-search () (interactive) (helm-do-grep-1 '("/home/vaughn/src") '(4) nil '("*.clj" "*.cljs")))
(global-set-key (kbd "<f1>") 'project-search)